# JQuery, Fixed header on scroll down issue in data-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have given data-table and trying fixed header while scroll down.
below datable displayed.

```
 <table class="temp1 table table-striped dataTable  mt-2 table-bordered" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" role="grid"
                  aria-describedby="user-list-page-info" id="user-list-table">
  <thead id="taablehead">
   <tr class="ligth" style="margin-left: 2px;">        
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>               
    <tr class="ligth">
      <tr class="table-info" id="row2" style="background-color: #dadbde;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input"></td>            
        <td>10001</td>
        <td>karan</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="table-info" id="row3" style="background-color: #dadbde;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input"></td>                         
        <td>10002</td>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="table-info" id="row4" style="background-color: #dadbde;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input"></td>            
        <td>10003</td>
        <td>rahul</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

i am trying to fix header on scroll down using below js but didn't work.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {            
      var table = $('.temp1').DataTable({         
          fixedHeader: true,
          scrollX: true
      });          
    } );
```

but given error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined`  i have tried with datatbale js, but didn't work.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sir, i have tried above given link solution, didn't works.

Comment: `Cannot set property of undefined` in [tag:datatables] frequently means your column definitions don't match the data supplied.  Unclear if it's the case here, just frequently.

Comment: You do have a *number* of typos, specifically `<td</td>` which will cause your columns/headers to mismatch.  (and `ligth` but that's just styling, probably)

Comment: Note that your error is unrelated to fixedHeader - get it working without extra options *first*.

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry it's typo mistake.  `<td></td>`

Comment: Wasn't the issue - though does create a lopsided datatable.  Issue is `<tr><tr></tr></tr>`

Comment: @vvp45 Why do you have TR inside a TR`?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen tr inside tr given cause need to child rows differentiate from parents rows

Comment: @vvp45 TR as a direct parent of another tr is not valid

Comment: @vvp45 You are also duplicating ID's and that is also bad

Comment: @vp45 - if you want child/nested data, then you can use this officially supported approach: [Child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by having a nested `<tr>`

```
<tbody>
  <tr class='ligth'>
        <tr>
```

Removing that (and not fixing the other typos) removes the error:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('.temp1').DataTable({
      fixedHeader: true,
      scrollX: true      
  });
});
```

```html
<link  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="temp1 table table-striped dataTable  mt-2 table-bordered" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" role="grid"
                  aria-describedby="user-list-page-info" id="user-list-table">
  <thead id="taablehead">
   <tr class="ligth" style="margin-left: 2px;">
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>               
      <tr class="table-info" id="row2" style="background-color: #dadbde;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input"></td>
        <td</td>
        <td</td>
        <td>10001</td>
        <td>karan</td>
        <td>A</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="table-info" id="row2" style="background-color: #dadbde;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input"></td>             
        <td</td>
        <td</td>
        <td>10002</td>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>B</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="table-info" id="row2" style="background-color: #dadbde;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input"></td>
        <td</td>
        <td</td>
        <td>10003</td>
        <td>rahul</td>
        <td>C</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Freedom there is lots of `<td</td>` also the amount of td dont match th in head

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's typo mistake `<td></td> correction done. please check code.

Comment: The issue was `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined` - this is unrelated to fixed headers and unrelated to OPs original `<td<td>` typo.  The above snippet fixes the issue, not all the other problems that OP may or may not have.   You may notice that this snippet does not give `Uncaught TypeError`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen exactly, proving that that's not the issue and the issue is entirely down to nested `tr`

Comment: tr inside tr given cause need to child rows differentiate from parents rows.

Comment: As asserted by @CarstenLøvboAndersen a `tr` directly inside another `tr` is not valid HTML (and (clearly) not allowed by datatables as it gives your error).